# How to do a database check and depending on results either update or insert (keep getting a HTTP 500 error)

Tags: php, mysqli, sql-update

I am trying to build a way to do an input field update check that looks to see if a user input field is empty or not. And then depending on answer if it is empty or not do more checks. So for example if the input field is empty I want it to be ignored so rest of code runs, And if there is a value inside of the input field some more checks will be done to check if it is inside the database or not, and if it is not inside the database then it must be inserted into the database, and if it is already in then just update that field.
The table is a relational one to a main table where `inf_id` is the main table and `userid` is the relational one i am working in

So I have tried to do it in different way however I keep running into problems and each time I make a mistake or something that doesn't work I get a `HTTP 500 error` page saying it can't be reached. I have also tried to do a change the `name` in the input to other things to see if that effects and different layouts or such neither works I feel like it is something small that I am missing out on
also tired but i may have done it incorrectly since I never really used this before

```sql
IF EXISTS (SELECT count(*) FROM `table` WHERE inf_id = $infid)
   BEGIN UPDATE GOES HERE END ELSE BEGIN INSERT GOES HERE END
```

This is my Code in the form to check the database has inputs, if it doesn't it creates a blank input. However If there is values in the database then it will echo it out

```php
$vId = $_GET['i']; //this is the users unique ID that is send in the query string for testing purpose

if (mysqli_num_rows($rs_username) == 0 ){
   echo '<input type="text" name="currentusername[]" class="currentusername" placeholder="Current Bikes" >';
} else {
   while ($rs_bike_rows = mysqli_fetch_assoc($rs_bikes)) {
       echo '<input type="text" name="currentusername[]" class="currentusername" value="' . $row['currentusername'] . '">';
       echo '<input type="hidden" name="userid[]" value="' . $row['userid'] . '">';
       echo '<button type="button" onclick="return deleteFromDbBike('. $rs_bike_rows['oid'] .', '. $vId .');">Delete</button>';
   }
}
```

This is to sanitize the inputs that the users inputs in a process file

```php
if (isset($_POST['currentusername']) && $_POST['currentusername'] !== '') {
    $currentusername = $_POST['currentusername'];
    $allusername = '';

    foreach ($vcurrentbike as $users) {
         $allusername .= $users. ' ';
    }

    if (filter_var($allusername , FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING) === null) {
        $vValidation++;
    }
} else {
   $currentusername= '';
}
```

later on in the process file to then check the input value and update/insert it

```php
$user = $_POST['userid'];

if ($currentusername != '') {
     for ($i = 0; $i < count($user); $i++) {
        $userid = $bike[$i];
        $valueuser = $currentusername[$i];

        $sqlcheck = "Select `inf_id` FROM usertable WHERE inf_id = $vId";
        $resultcheck = mysqli_query($conn,$sqlcheck);

        if (mysqli_num_rows($resultcheck) >= 1) {
            $stmt = $conn->prepare("UPDATE usertable SET currentusername = ? WHERE inf_id = ? and userid = ?");
            $stmt->bind_param("sii", $currentperson, $infid, $ownedid);

            $currentperson = $valueuser ;
            $infid = $vid;
            $ownedid = $userid;

            $stmt->execute();

            //the update code works (tried and tested) just using 
            //exit to see where the code goes.
            exit('1');

         } else {
            //this is where the insert value would be however I can  
            //never get it to echo 0 when it exits; instead i just get a HTTP 500;
            exit('0');
         }

     };
} else {
   exit('fails');
}
```

In the End I want it to be able to check if the user has inputted values and then depending on if they have or have not then either insert or update it. and if the user hasn't just ignore it. and move onto the next field

> Edit 
>   it basically has 2 levels to this statement
>   Level 1:
>   1.1) if user input is empty then ignore it completely.
>   1.2) if user input has a value check it against the database
>   Level 2:
>   2.1) if the value exists in database then update the values
>   2.2) if the values don't exists then insert it into the database.
>   Error I'm running into is that if the value is not in the database to begin with it will create an empty input field.
>   Now when a user then adds text to the empty field it wants to update it but it doesn't exists. so through out errors at me as there is nothing to update
>   The States of the input field can be :
>   1) empty with no value at all
>   2) Has a value now added so it is not in the db
>   3) has a value from initial submission of form that is in db
>
> EDIT 2: add more button

```
<button type="button" onclick="addMoreRows('user')"> Add More Current Usernames</button>
<div id="currentuser"></div>
```

```
var itemTypes = {
    user:{
        maxLimit: 4,
        currentCount: 1,
        selector: '#currentuser',
        newElement: '<div class="moreusersadd"><input type="text" name="currentusernameadd[]" class="currentusernameadd" placeholder="Current Bikes" ><button class="delete" onclick="deleteRow(this, \'user\')">Delete</button></div>'
    }
}
function addMoreRows(type){
    var item = itemTypes[type];
    if (item.currentCount < item.maxLimit) {
        item.currentCount++;
        $(item.selector).append(item.newElement);
    }
    else {
        alert('You Have Reached the limits')
    }
}
function deleteRow(event, type){
  $(event).parent('div').remove();
  itemTypes[type].currentCount--;
};
```

Comment: This isn't very clear, am i right in saying you want to create an input for each row in your table so that you can update existing ones and then have an extra input to add extras?

Comment: mysqli_num_rows is checking the $resultcheck which is an array of the results from the DB. Thus you either need to rather count the array total and check if empty and not the mysqli_num_rows. Or add what is currently in the mysqli_query, into the mysql_num_rows. Or do a SQL COUNT(*) all as your select, which will return you the rows count.

Comment: @PaddyHallihan yea so if the theres isnt anything in DB and user puts in an input then i want it to be created but if there is already a value in the database then i want it to be updated

Comment: @w3shivers I have done `SQL COUNT(*)` before and that also does not work

Comment: @PaddyHallihan I want it to look at the input. And if there is no value then ignore the input and continue with code. however if there is a value i want it to check if it is in the Database, if it is then update that value if there is not a value then insert it into the database. does that help you?

Answer (score 0):

I think this is kind of what you want.

I used my own users table as an example but you should be able to just change the queries to your own tables and columns.

If you have any issue with it just show us your full table structure and I can update it.

```
<?php
include_once("web/connection.php");

echo "<form method='POST' action='test.php'>";
echo "<table>";
$sql = "SELECT * FROM users";
$stmt = DB::run($sql);
$count = $stmt->rowCount();
while($row = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)){
    $id = $row['id'];
    $username = $row['username'];
    $password = $row['password'];
    echo "<tr>";
    echo "<td><input type='text' name='username_".$id."' value='".$username."'></td>";
    echo "<td><input type='text' name='password_".$id."' value='".$password."'></td>";
    echo "</tr>";
}
echo "<tr>";
echo "<td><input type='text' name='username' placeholder='Username'></td>";
echo "<td><input type='text' name='password' placeholder='Password'></td>";
echo "</tr>";
echo "<tr><td colspan='2'><input type='submit'></td></tr>";
echo "</table>";
echo "</form>";

for($i=1; $i<=$count; $i++){
    if(isset($_POST['username_'.$i]) && isset($_POST['password_'.$i])){
        $username = $_POST['username_'.$i];
        $password = $_POST['password_'.$i];
        
        $params = [$username,$password,$i];
        $sql = "UPDATE users SET username=?, password=? WHERE id=?";
        $stmt = DB::run($sql,$params);
    }
}

if(isset($_POST['username']) && isset($_POST['password'])){
    $username = $_POST['username'];
    $password = $_POST['password'];
    
    $params = [$username,$password];
    $sql = "INSERT INTO users (username, password) VALUES (?,?)";
    $stmt = DB::run($sql,$params);
}
?>
```

### Edit

So this now has the added header to refresh the page and update the table after each submit.

I also added a check to make sure the new fields weren't blank so it wasn't adding an empty row. And you can now also add as many input rows as you want.

```
<?php
session_start();
include_once("web/connection.php");

echo "<form method='POST' action='test.php'>";
echo "<table>";
$sql = "SELECT * FROM users";
$stmt = DB::run($sql);
$count = $stmt->rowCount();
while($row = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)){
    $id = $row['id'];
    $username = $row['username'];
    $password = $row['password'];
    echo "<tr>";
    echo "<td><input type='text' name='username_".$id."' value='".$username."'></td>";
    echo "<td><input type='text' name='password_".$id."' value='".$password."'></td>";
    echo "</tr>";
}
if(isset($_POST['no_of_inputs'])){
    $_SESSION['new_number'] = $_POST['no_of_inputs'];
    for($i=1; $i<=$_SESSION['new_number']; $i++){
        echo "<tr>";
        echo "<td><input type='text' name='new_username_".$i."' placeholder='Username'></td>";
        echo "<td><input type='text' name='new_password_".$i."' placeholder='Password'></td>";
        echo "</tr>";
    }
}
echo "<tr><td colspan='2'><input type='submit'></td></tr>";
echo "</table>";
echo "</form>";

echo "<form method='POST' action='test.php'>";
echo "Add <input type='number' name='no_of_inputs' onchange='this.form.submit()'> rows";
echo "</form>";

for($i=1; $i<=$count; $i++){
    if(isset($_POST['username_'.$i]) && isset($_POST['password_'.$i])){
        $username = $_POST['username_'.$i];
        $password = $_POST['password_'.$i];
        
        $params = [$username,$password,$i];
        $sql = "UPDATE users SET username=?, password=? WHERE id=?";
        $stmt = DB::run($sql,$params);
    }
}

if(isset($_SESSION['new_number'])){
    for($i=1; $i<=$_SESSION['new_number']; $i++){
        if((isset($_POST['new_username_'.$i]) && $_POST['new_username_'.$i]!="") && (isset($_POST['new_password_'.$i]) && $_POST['new_password_'.$i]!="")){
            $username = $_POST['new_username_'.$i];
            $password = $_POST['new_password_'.$i];
            
            $params = [$username,$password];
            $sql = "INSERT INTO users (username, password) VALUES (?,?)";
            $stmt = DB::run($sql,$params);
            header('location: test.php');
            unset($_SESSION['new_number']);
        }
    }
}
?>
```

This works and is tested but if you want the basic table structure is:

```
CREATE TABLE `users` (
 `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
 `username` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
 `password` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
 PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
)
```

In regards to the connection you can change the queries from how I did them like so:

Instead of:

```
$params = [$username,$password];
$sql = "INSERT INTO users (username, password) VALUES (?,?)";
$stmt = DB::run($sql,$params);
```

You could do something like this:

```
$stmt = $conn->prepare("INSERT INTO users (username, password) VALUES (?,?)");
$stmt->bind_param($username,$password);
$stmt->execute();
```

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion or debugging sessions; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/190881/discussion-on-answer-by-paddy-hallihan-how-to-do-a-database-check-and-depending). Please make sure that the answer has been [edit]ed to incorporate all relevant information.